# Custom ImageView doesn't display image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created on custom imageView class. And am trying to override the image setter method. But for some reason the imageView is not displaying anything, though the image is getting assigned onto it.

The code is as follows:

```
@implementation CustomImageView

@synthesize image = _image;

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)correctedImage
{
    _image = correctedImage;
}

@end
```

I have tried removing the setter method. i.e Without overriding any method at all. Still it is not displaying anything. :(

Comment: What is `@synthesize image = _image;` ? Your custom `image` ?

Comment: I just needed to access the image property without invoking the accessor method

Comment: Remove the synthesis statement and it will work.

Comment: I can't access _image if I remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had to set the image by passing it to the super.

```
[super setImage: correctedImage];
```

Simply, setting it from the base class doesn't seen to work :/